# Test two synchronized methods in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a list and two threads. One is adding values to the list and waiting for the list to get empty and the other one is removing values. The code looks like this:

```
public void addValueToList(String value) {
    list.add(value);
    waitForListToGetEmpty();
}

private synchronized waitForListToGetEmpty() {
    while ( !this.list.isEmpty() ) {
         try  {
            this.wait();
         }  catch ( final InterruptedException e ) { }
      }
}

private synchronized removeValueFromList(int index) {
    this.list.remove(index);
    if (this.list.isEmpty()) {
         this.notify();
    }
}
```

My problem is testing the code above. I have tried something like this:

```
public void testAddValueToList() {
     Thread addValueThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            addValueToList("new value");
         }
      }
      addValueThread.start();
}

public void testRemoveValueFromList() {
    Thread removeValueThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            removeValueFromList(0);
         }
      }
    removeValueThread.start();
}
```

The problem is that the two tests run successfully but it seems like the first  `run` in which I call `addValueToList` is never exectuted. Can anyone help me with some ideas to test this?

Comment: Do you guarantee that the test run in the right order?

Comment: I don't know that. I think this should be fixed somehow because the first method adds something to the list then it waits until the other thread removes that value. So these two threads shoud run simultaneosly no?

Comment: Just a sidenote: What's the point in using a list, when there is going to be only one elemnt in it , ever ... or is this just some kind of experiment?

Comment: How can you tell that the add didn't happen.. If the remove happens before the add you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` unless there is already something in the list before the tests are run. But you say that both tests are successful?

Comment: please add `removeValueFromList() ` above

Comment: On a sidenote: Why is  `removeValueFromList(...)`  synchronized and `addValueToList()` not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine if `addValueThread` runs first and adds avalue to list but before it calls `waitForListToGetEmpty()` , JVM starts `removeValueThread` and it calls `removeValueFromList()` in the process it grabs the lock and ends up calling `notify()` before `addValueThread` is blocked by `wait()`.

synchronize your `addValueToList()` so `addValueThread` immediately grabs the lock , also `removeValueFromList()` can throw an  exception if `removeValueThread`  runs first

Comment: I have added a `notify()` inside `removeValueFromList` but the effect is the same. It seems like the `removeValueThread` finishes before the `addValueThread`...